# System.IO.Compression Reference issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

I am working on .NET framework 4.6 Web API application. My app is working on my machine and I was able to build it in my local but when I push it to our Azure Dev OPS CI, I got this build error.

```
Error CS0433: The type 'ZipArchive' exists in both 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
: Error CS0433: The type 'ZipArchiveMode' exists in both 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Comment: Why are you targeting 4.6? You _need_ to update to 4.8 ASAP due to massive breaking changes in TLS support.

Comment: It looks like you are referencing two different versions of the same DLL. Without knowing more about your project can't say for sure what is causing that. I would guess most likely you have a dependency that also has a reference to that DLL causing the conflict, but it can be other reasons as well.

Comment: Somehow your CI machine has multiple copies of the same assembly?

Comment: You'll get 4.0.0.0 if you target 4.6, but 4.2.0.0 if the target is 4.7.2 or greater.  Simplest way to get ahead is to bump up to at least 4.7.2 so everybody can agree that 4.2.0.0 is the one you want.